# What's the right way to use CoreData in an AppIntent?

Tags: swift, swiftui, core-data, appintents

I have an AppIntent (introduced in iOS 16.0) that utilizes my Core Data store. If I enable CoreData's concurrency debugging (add this argument to scheme `-com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug 1`), I get errors while my app is running.

I've begun using background contexts from my container in conjunction with `context.performAndWait` and am able to avoid the concurrency error.

Is this the right way to use CoreData within an AppIntent, or is there a different pattern I should be leveraging?

Comment: It’s hard to be specific without seeing how your code works but in general using `perform` or `performAndWait` is always the right way to use Core Data.

Comment: I use `perform` and `performAndWait` always for save and deletes, but this is for fetch requests, which I don't normally wrap in a `perform`. Should I be doing that?

Comment: @stanlemon Yes, unless you’re certain that your code is running on the main queue *and* you are using a main-queue context.